# python daemon - why does this function kill parent twice?

Tags: python, linux, unix, daemon

```
def daemon_start(pid_file, log_file):

    def handle_exit(signum, _):
        if signum == signal.SIGTERM:
            sys.exit(0)
        sys.exit(1)

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_exit)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handle_exit)

    # fork only once because we are sure parent will exit
    pid = os.fork()
    assert pid != -1

    if pid > 0:
        # parent waits for its child
        time.sleep(5)
        sys.exit(0)

    # child signals its parent to exit
    ppid = os.getppid()
    pid = os.getpid()
    if write_pid_file(pid_file, pid) != 0:
        os.kill(ppid, signal.SIGINT)
        sys.exit(1)

    os.setsid()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, signal.SIG_IGN)

    print('started')

    os.kill(ppid, signal.SIGTERM)

    sys.stdin.close()
    try:
        freopen(log_file, 'a', sys.stdout)
        freopen(log_file, 'a', sys.stderr)
    except IOError as e:
        shell.print_exception(e)
        sys.exit(1)
```

This daemon does not use double fork. It says "fork only once because we are sure parent will exit". Parent calls sys.exit(0) to exit.However child calls os.kill(ppid, signal.SIGTERM) to exit parent.

What does it mean by doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "double fork" is a standard technique to ensure a daemon is reparented to the init (pid 1) process so that the shell which launched it does not kill it. This is actually using that technique because the first fork is done by the process that launched the python program. When a program calls `daemon_start` it forks. The original (now parent) process exits a few seconds later or sooner when the child it forked signals it. That will cause the kernel to reparent the child process to pid 1. "Double fork" does not mean the daemon calls `fork()` twice.

Also, your subject line asks "why does this function kill parent twice?" But the code in question does no such thing. I have no idea how you got that idea.